# How to display item vue when i click on vue listing all items?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api, dynamic-routing

I am new on vueJS/Nuxt and i a building a blog using wordpress as headless CMS. Wordpress expose data from rest api and in vuejs i use those data and display them on page. 
I have this project structure :
[image]

I am facing a problem when i move from portraits/index.vue to portraits/_slug.vue.
- portraits/index.vue display all my custom post type portraits. Here is the code :

```
   <template>
      <div>
        <app-masthead></app-masthead>
        <div class="portraits">
          <main>
            <div class="portrait" v-for="portrait in sortedPortraits" :key="portrait.id">
              <h3>
                <a :href="`portraits/${portrait.slug}`">{{ portrait.title.rendered }}</a>
              </h3>
              <small>{{ portrait.date | dateformat }}</small>
              <div v-html="portrait.excerpt.rendered"></div>
              <a :href="`portraits/${portrait.slug}`" class="readmore slide">Read more ⟶</a>
            </div>
          </main>
          <aside>
            <h2 class="tags-title">Tags</h2>
            <div class="tags-list">
              <ul>
                <li
                  @click="updateTag(tag)"
                  v-for="tag in tags"
                  :key="tag.id"
                  :class="[tag.id === selectedTag ? activeClass : '']"
                >
                  <a>{{ tag.name }}</a>
                  <span v-if="tag.id === selectedTag">✕</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import AppMasthead from "@/components/AppMasthead.vue";

    export default {
      components: {
        AppMasthead
      },
      data() {
        return {
          selectedTag: null,
          activeClass: "active"
        };
      },
      computed: {
        portraits() {
          return this.$store.state.portraits;
        },
        tags() {
          return this.$store.state.tags;
        },
        sortedPortraits() {
          if (!this.selectedTag) return this.portraits;
          return this.portraits.filter(el => el.tags.includes(this.selectedTag));
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.$store.dispatch("getPortraits");
      },
      methods: {
        updateTag(tag) {
          if (!this.selectedTag) {
            this.selectedTag = tag.id;
          } else {
            this.selectedTag = null;
          }
        }
      }
    };
    </script>

    <style lang="scss">


    </style>

- portraits/_slug.vue display one item portrait. Here is the code : 
<template>
  <main class="portrait individual">
    <h1>{{ portrait.title.rendered }}</h1>
    <small class="date">{{ portrait.date | dateformat }}</small>
    <section v-html="portrait.content.rendered"></section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    portraits() {
      return this.$store.state.portraits;
    },
    portrait() {
      debugger
      return this.portraits.find(el => el.slug === this.slug);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      slug: this.$route.params.slug
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getPortraits");
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

When i click on readmore i have the following error :

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

[image]

and this method is not call

```
portrait() {
      debugger
      return this.portraits.find(el => el.slug === this.slug);
    }
```

My portrait is not initialised ! 
What i am missing please ? 
Thanks

Comment: "_When i click on readmore i have the following error_" what error are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, i've just updated my question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way.

```
<template>
  <main class="portrait individual">
    <h1 v-if="portrait">{{ portrait.title.rendered }}</h1>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    portraits() {
      return this.$store.state.portraits;
    },
    portrait() {
      return this.portraits.find(el => el.slug === this.slug);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      slug: this.$route.params.slug
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.commit("getPortraits");
  }
};
</script>
```

It seems `this.$store.dispatch("getPortraits");` is not invoked.

Instead of that, [You can use](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store) `this.$store.commit("getPortraits");` in `created()`.

In *store/index.js*.

```js
export const state = () => ({
  portraits: []
});

export const mutations = {
  getPortraits(state) {
    state.portraits.push({
      slug: "a",
      title: {
        rendered: "hello"
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I tried in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bose-4swcx?file=/pages/_slug/index.vue).

In another way, you can also use *portraits* data in `data()` object.

```
<template>
  <main class="portrait individual">
    <h1 v-if="portrait">{{ portrait.title.rendered }}</h1>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    portrait() {
      return this.portraits.find(el => el.slug === this.slug);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      slug: this.$route.params.slug,
      portraits: this.$store.state.portraits
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.commit("getPortraits");
  }
};
</script>
```

And use `v-if="portrait"` in *h1* tag because portrait object might be initial value like undefined or empty array.